# Is there a hidden condition in these T&C?

Tags: credit-card, terminology, reward-program

I went through a FAQ on a website regarding an offer where it mentioned customers using a particular credit card can get a 10% discount. The minimum limit to get the discount is Rs. 6000.

> **1. What is the offer?**
>
> Get 10% cashback on the site (website and mobile) and 15% cashback on
>   the app on successful single transaction net of refunds on purchases
>   of Rs. 6000 and above from 1st to 5th Oct 2016. Cancelled items/orders
>   will not be eligible for cashback. Additionally get 5% Cashback (in
>   the form of reward points) on XXX Bank Debit cards, max upto Rs.
>   500.Detailed T&C for extra 5% cashback here < link >
>
> **4. What is the minimum transaction size for the cashback for the duration of the event (1st to 5th Oct '16)?**
>
> The minimum transaction size for the cashback duration is Rs. 6000 in
>   a single transaction net of refunds and cancellations.

Here when they say "single transaction", they mean the offer is not applicable if you make more than one transaction to reach the maximum limit, i.e., Rs. 6000.

That's not a problem, but could anybody tell me if it also means that the offer is valid only on "one" transaction (and it is not applicable if you try to make more than one transaction)?

Please note that I am not asking a legal question. I just had a debate with my brother and there were some silly arguments. I am just trying to know if the offer page has all details and request the company to update their page.

Also, I requested one of their support team to forward this to their content writers and update the page with a new FAQ specifying a limit on "number of transactions" if they have such a condition. That would be a valid point and helps customers like me and the company. The staff misunderstood as if I am asking for an extra discount (normally support representatives try to fix issues on their end and would not forward to the higher level when they assume they are right).

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be a few FAQ's missing in there, are you sure they are unimportant?

Comment: @RCarpenter They are not directly related to my doubt so I haven't posted them. Here are they: http://ge.tt/2vJdEIf2

Comment: I would say the wording of FAQ #2 makes it important to at least part of your doubt, as it has wording that would suggest that you can only receive the reward a single time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider this a legal question as it involves the parsing of a contract.  What this says as interpreted by a lawyer/court may not be what the company intended.

Personally, I don't see a clear answer either way.  The combination of the word 'single' and the plural 'purchases' implies that this is applicable for multiple transactions as long as they are more than Rs. 6000 (after subtracting refunds) but if this makes a big difference to you either way, you should get clarification/confirmation from the company.

Comment: I disagree that simply by the word being plural it would imply that this is available for multiple counts per person. The term being plural could just as likely suggest all purchases made by all parties.

Comment: @RCarpenter It could vary from country to country but I think that would be an unusual interpretation in any country with a legal tradition based on English common law.